# how to create a persistent offline database with electron and pouchdb

Tags: mongodb, couchdb, electron, pouchdb, nosql

i am going to write a desktop-app that should be able to store its mass-data persistent and locally.

i want to write that app with [electron](https://github.com/electron/electron). later, i want to port the app to mobile. i am experimenting here with nativescript and the [angular-advanced-seed](https://github.com/NathanWalker/angular-seed-advanced) which tries to make it possible to reuse code on different platforms.

As Database-tool i want to use [pouchdb](https://pouchdb.com/) because i didn't want to have the user setup/install an additional tool for having a database for the desktop-app which runs seperately.

Also, I like to use pouchdb, because it has this nice sync feature with [couchdb](http://couchdb.apache.org/), which i can possibly use later in the project when the need for sync with an online database will arise.

Now my Questions

1. how can i use pouchdb to store data locally (it can be a mass of data that exceeds the localstorage limit) even when the app has been stopped by the user. i need to load that data in the app, when the user starts the desktop-app the next time. i read about pouchdb using leveldb, but i can't find the data persisted.
2. is it possible in electron to have a database running inside the electron-app, so that i do not need to install for example mongodb on the users pc/mobile app too?
3. it would be nice to have a solution that will work on mobile (ios/android) too, so that i have the offline capabilities too there without using a different approach for the data-storage
4. Are there any other solutions (combinations of) database tools to satisfy my needs: A. same offline storage capabilities for mass data, that exceeds localstorage' space restrictions for Desktop (electron)/Mobile (Android/IOS) and Web and B. good sync-function to the online-pendant database like (pouchdb/couchdb or minimongo/mongodb) C. in-app database should have the same query api like the server-database (minimongo/mongodb)

thx in advance for your tipps.

Comment: if you were able to find any solution kindly share . i am facing same issue? thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Pouchdb-Server works. I have an app setup with [express-pouchdb](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-pouchdb).

```
'use strict'

console.log('Starting PouchDB...');

const express = require('express');
const PouchDB = require('pouchdb');
const app = express();

app.use('/', require('express-pouchdb')(PouchDB.defaults({prefix: '.db/'}), {
      overrideMode: {
        include: ['routes/fauxton']
      }
    })
);

app.listen(3000);
```

Then I just acquire this in your `index.html` file.

```
<script type="text/javascript">require('./pouchdb-app.js');</script>
```

Electron starts pulled the index.html and starts pouchdb for you.

Currently, I am trying to get [rxdb](https://github.com/pubkey/rxdb) to work.

Note:

```
overrideMode: {
   include: ['routes/fauxton']
}
```

Remove the above for production. See [fauxton](https://github.com/apache/couchdb-fauxton) for information on it.

---

Just realized if you check out RxDB's electron [example](https://github.com/pubkey/rxdb/tree/master/examples/electron). It will help you run just Pouchdb-Server (if you don't want the express app) through using [concurrently](https://www.npmjs.com/package/concurrently).

From the example, package.json:

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "concurrently \"npm run server\" \"npm run electron\"",
    "electron": "electron .",
    "server": "pouchdb-server --host 0.0.0.0 -p 10102 -m -d /tmp/pouchdb-server/ -n true"
```

You, then, can use PouchDB instead Angular and just do the same as I did above to access the server.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like pouchdb-server could fit your needs: https://github.com/pouchdb/pouchdb-server